# Overloading the output operator for both the base class and its derived class (C++)

Tags: c++

this is a question on overloading the output operator in C++:
How do you overload << on BOTH the base class and the derived class? Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


class Base{
public:
virtual char* name(){ return "All your base belong to us.";}
};

class Child : public Base{
public:
virtual char* name(){ return "All your child belong to us.";}
};


ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Base &b){
output << "To Base: " << b.name() ;
return output;}

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Child &b){
output << "To Child: " << b.name() ;
return output;}


int main(){

Base* B;
B = new Child;

cout << *B << endl;

return 0;

}
```

The output is

```
To Base: All your child belong to us."
```

so the name() in Child shadowed that of Base; but the overloading of << does not descend from Base to Child. How can I overload << such that, when its argument is in Base it uses ONLY the Base version of << ?

I want "To Child: All your child belong to us." to be output in this case.

Comment: The version of `operator<<` that is being used *is* `operator<<( ostream&, Base& );`. The (non-) problem is that `name()` is virtual in `Base` so this version of `op<<` is calling the "correct" version of `name()` based on the dynamic type of the object being output.

Comment: It's not shadowed, it's overridden.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  The fact that it prints "child" means that it is correctly calling `Child::name` at runtime.  Why does it matter that it's calling `operator<<(ostream&, Base &)`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I think the OP wants `operator<<` to behave as if it were virtual.

Comment: @Philipp: Actually, after re-reading the question, I think the OP wants the opposite of virtual behaviour.  He wants `operator <<(ostream &, Base &)` to call `Base::name`.

Comment: @pfng: Can you clarify exactly what you want the output to be?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That might also be the case. Pfng, please clarify what you actually want.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  Thanks guys! I want "To Child: All your child belong to us." Other comments mentioned that one can simply put whatever overloaded to << to name(), but that's not handy say, when you want audio1 to be played whenever you << a Base object, and audio2 for a Child object.

Comment: @pfng: Then just put all the virtual behaviour into the virtual function that is called by `operator<<` (this doesn't have to be `name`), I don't see why this is a big deal.  (Incidentally, I would argue that playing audio when using `<<` is not usually the expected behaviour...!)

Answer (score 9):

Make it a virtual function.

```
class Base{
public:
  virtual const char* name() const { return "All your base belong to us.";}
  inline friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Base &b)
  {
    return b.out(output);
  }
private:
  virtual ostream& out(ostream& o) const { return o << "To Base: " << name(); }
};

class Child : public Base{
public:
  virtual const char* name() const { return "All your child belong to us.";}
private:
  virtual ostream& out(ostream& o) const { return o << "To Child: " << name(); }
};
```

Comment: Well, sure.  But this doesn't really add anything that isn't already happening.

Comment: It should print `"To Child"` instead of `"To Base"`.

Comment: I realise that.  But it's a trivial extension of the code that the OP already has.  (It's only one step removed from putting the `"To Base:"` inside the `name()` method.)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){

Base* B;
B = new Child;

cout << ( Child &) *B << endl;

return 0;

}
```